# Parsing /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking, configuration

Is there a C or C++ library available for parsing, editing, and writing */etc/network/interfaces* on Linux (in the form described at http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html)?

Comment: Before this question gets closed as opinion-based / too-broad: I am 99.99% sure that if such a library exists, there is only one of them -- i.e. I am pretty sure this is a question with a single, objectively correct answer.

Comment: If there is one, it seems even the Gnome NetworkManager people aren't aware of it: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2010-August/msg00077.html I also see references to awk scripts, etc. Seems everyone rolls their own.

Comment: I would rather parse the active network interfaces from `/proc/net/` ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://augeas.net/

Augeas is a configuration editing tool. It parses configuration files in their native formats and transforms them into a tree. Configuration changes are made by manipulating this tree and saving it back into native config files.

Comment: I needed this library years ago!

Comment: and now you'll have it forever